# LocalProxy objects in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, werkzeug

I'm using a lot of werkzeug.local.LocalProxy objects in my Flask app.  They are supposed to be perfect stand-ins for objects, but they aren't really, since they don't respond to type() or instanceof() correctly.

SQLAlchemy doesn't like them at all.  If I make a LocalProxy to a SQLAlchemy record, SQLAlchemy considers it to be None.  If I pass it a LocalProxy to a simpler type, it just says it's the wrong type.

[Here's an example of Flask-SQLAlchemy having a bad time with LocalProxy](https://gist.github.com/nickretallack/ec096a8013046c42d8f9).

How do you guys deal with this problem?  Just call _get_current_object() a lot?  It'd be pretty cool if SQLAlchemy or Flask-SQLAlchemy could automatically handle these LocalProxy objects more gracefully, especially considering Flask-Login uses them, and pretty much everybody uses that, right?

I'm considering adding this function to my project to deal with it, and wrapping any of my localproxies in it before passing them to sqlalchemy:

```
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy

def real(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, LocalProxy):
        return obj._get_current_object()
    return obj
```

Answer (score 0):

I patched the drivers used by `SQLAlchemy`, but I fear that it is not the most generic solution.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy as FlaskSQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy


class SQLAlchemy(FlaskSQLAlchemy):
    """Implement or overide extension methods."""

    def apply_driver_hacks(self, app, info, options):
        """Called before engine creation."""
        # Don't forget to apply hacks defined on parent object.
        super(SQLAlchemy, self).apply_driver_hacks(app, info, options)

        if info.drivername == 'sqlite':
            from sqlite3 import register_adapter

            def adapt_proxy(proxy):
                """Get current object and try to adapt it again."""
                return proxy._get_current_object()

            register_adapter(LocalProxy, adapt_proxy)

        elif info.drivername == 'postgresql+psycopg2':  # pragma: no cover
            from psycopg2.extensions import adapt, register_adapter

            def adapt_proxy(proxy):
                """Get current object and try to adapt it again."""
                return adapt(proxy._get_current_object())

            register_adapter(LocalProxy, adapt_proxy)

        elif info.drivername == 'mysql+pymysql':  # pragma: no cover
            from pymysql import converters

            def escape_local_proxy(val, mapping):
                """Get current object and try to adapt it again."""
                return converters.escape_item(
                    val._get_current_object(),
                    self.engine.dialect.encoding,
                    mapping=mapping,
                )

            converters.encoders[LocalProxy] = escape_local_proxy
```

Original source can be found [here](https://github.com/jirikuncar/invenio-db/blob/600757f20a88ce18a60ce4e75c501575137e8fa6/invenio_db/shared.py).